# CSS background color + image fade on hover with ease effect

Tags: html, css

I currently have a div with an image as a background, styled as so:

```
        #portfolio-1 {
        background:
        url(images/portfolio-1.jpg);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

I am then changing the background image on hover, so that it has a sort of red overlay on-top of it with the following css:

```
        #portfolio-1:hover {
        background: /* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */
        linear-gradient( rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45),
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)),
        /* bottom, image */
        url(images/portfolio-1.jpg);
        background-size: 100% 100%;

    }
```

This works as expected and the image instantly has a red layer over it, however I cannot seem to add an ease effect so that the transition happens over X seconds.
I have tried using

```
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

and

```
            transition: background 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease;
```

but have had no success.

Comment: You easily can put another div infront with ease

Comment: put that transition code in `#portfolio-1` and you need not to repeat css in `#portfolio-1:hover`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code on the `#portfolio-1` class which background color you would like to change:

```
   -webkit-transition: background 2s ease;
   -moz-transition: background 2s ease;
   -o-transition: background 2s ease;
   transition: background 2s ease;
```

And then in your `#portfolio-1:hover` class, add the following:

```
background: red;
```